# QuickTime doesn't appear, or is excessively delayed

Tags: quicktime

I have no problem view Apple trailers in little windows, but when I click on a link to download an HD version, it's supposed to load QuickTime, which then buffers the movie and eventually begins to play it.

On my previous computer (Vista/32), QuickTime would wait for a long time (30+ secs) to appear, and sometimes not at all.  Sometimes I could short-circuit the delay by clicking the link numerous times, or clicking somewhere else on the page, on another task window, or by pressing Alt-Tab.  I'll add that my previous system had three monitors.

My new computer (Win7/64) initially had only two monitors, and QT seemed to load better.  Now that I've added a third screen, I can't get it to run at all.

I've Googled about, but not found any solutions.  It sound like [this guy](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2250013&tstart=0) has the same problem, but there's no response to his message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I may have found the solution.

I started by checking my task list with Process Explorer from www.sysinternals.com.  QuickTimePlayer.exe was parked there, so I killed it.

Then when I clicked on a trailer link, a new instance of QT appeared in the process list, and QT's window appeared as expected.  The trailer played, and when it was finished I closed QT.

However, QuickTimePlayer.exe remained in the task list, and no more trailers would play.  I killed the task again, and then clicked on a trailer to bring QT up again.  This time I went to Edit / Preferences / QuickTime Preferences.  On the Streaming tab I turned OFF Instant On.

Now when I exit QT, the player task closes, and a fresh one appears when I play another movie.  This is exactly what I want it to do.